# Python Flask Server: Error 415 Unsupported Media Type when using jsonify

Tags: reactjs, json, flask

So I am having an issue where my Flask server is, to my knowledge, correctly:

1. Receiving a JSON object (dict of parameters) from my React web page
2. Creating a response prompt using those parameters.
3. Calling jsonify on that response prompt.

But it is not updating the Flask server correctly. The server starts with just displaying:
{
"error": "415 Unsupported Media Type: Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request     Content-Type was not 'application/json'.",
"success": false
}

and continues to display that even when the @app.route unction is called.
Anyone know what could be the issue here? The plan is to get this response prompt back to another React page that was created when the initial JSON object was created and sent to the Flask server.

```
`@app.route('/generate-location', methods=\['GET', 'POST'\])
def process_config():
    try:
    print("_____Data Here_______")
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    # Extract data from the JSON request
    parameters = {
    'foo': data.get('foo'),
    'bar' :data.get('bar'),
    'baz' :data.get('baz')
    }

    # Call genResponse to create dict containing response prompt
    response_dict = gen_response(parameters)

    unique = gen_id()
    print("______ID Created_______:")
    print(unique)

    configs[unique] = response_dict

    response_dict['unique_id'] = unique
    print("______response_______:")
    print(response_dict)

    return jsonify({'success': True, 'message': response_dict})
    except Exception as e:
    return jsonify({'success': False, 'error': str(e)})
```

`

I am printing data and response_dict (type is dict) and so far I can see the terminal output for what I want to display and so I think it lies with my requests to and from the server. Does jsonify not automatically correct the content type?

**EDIT:** Added js webpage request that sends POST request to flask server.
If I am understanding correctly, I am adding the 'Content-Type' in the POST request on my react page. I would like to see the output of my Flask function shown in 'http://localhost:5000/generate-location' so I am curious if I am doing it right.:

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
try {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/generate- 
location', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      foo,
      bar,
      baz
    }),
  });

  if (response.ok) {
    const responseData = await response.json();
    console.log("response below")
    console.log(responseData)
    // Navigate to a new page and pass the response data as a 
parameter
    setUniqueID(responseData.UniqueID)
    window.open('/generated-location-test/','_blank');
  } else {
    setResponseMessage(`Failed to submit configuration: 
${response.statusText}`);
  }
} catch (error) {
  setResponseMessage(`Error submitting configuration: 
${error.message}`);
}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem probably comes this line `data = request.get_json()`. Check the Flask documentation what it says about [`.get_json()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json)

> If the mimetype does not indicate JSON (application/json, see [is_json](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Request.is_json)), or parsing fails, [on_json_loading_failed()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Request.on_json_loading_failed) is called and its return value is used as the return value. By default this raises a 415 Unsupported Media Type resp.

When making a GET or POST request to your Flask server you should add the header `Content-Type: application/json` so it can parse it as json. With curl it can be something like this:

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"foo\": \"123\", \"bar\": \"abc\", \"baz\": \"xyz\"}" http://localhost:5000/generate-location`

with [Requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) (Python):

`requests.post("http://localhost:5000/generate-location", json={"foo": "123", "bar": "abc", "baz": "xyz"})`

Comment: I included an edit that shows what I am doing on my React web page that defines Content-Type. I think as Simon Echeverri said below, it would not make sense if the print statements pass after 'data = reqeust.get_json()' if that line was the issue. 

I did a console.log of responseData, which I assume is what is being sent in the POST request, and responseData shows up as a dict.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other response, you seem to be missing the header `Content-Type: application/json` when you do the request, however, I am intrigued you are able to see the print of `response_dict`, (because if it was the header, it would fail in the first line, it won't continue executing to the print), that makes me think it can be something to do with the `response_dict` dict. So if adding the header doesn't work, could you maybe show how the `response_dict` looks like? There are some dicts that have data types that are not JSON-valid (like NaNs for example)

Comment: print(data) shows the following:

{'foo': 'Village', 'bar': 'a', 'baz': 'b', 'qaz': 'c', 'param1': 'd', 'param2': 's', 'param2': 's', 'param3': 's', 'param4': 's', 'param5': 's', 'param6: 's', 'param7': False, 'param8': False}

Params 7 and 8 are booleans, everything else are strings (empty strings if no value is in the input box on the web page).

Comment: print(request_dict) also shows only strings and booleans? It seems the request is going through, I truly think it has to do with response_dict. Have you tried returning something else to see if you get the same error? Returning just two booleans in the jsonify?